# No error in the xml still R.java is not being created

Tags: android-manifest

I have build a project about logging accelerometer data. I added 1 new acitivity in my project called "StoryActivity" and one new layout for that activity named "Story.xml" . But suddenly the R.java file is gone. I searched a lot but couldn't find any error in my xml files or even in the manifest file. Am I missing something while updating with the activity? 
Here is my xml files-->
Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Start" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/startBtn"
        android:text="Acceleromter Values"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Accel_x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="Accel_x : " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Accel_y"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Accel_x"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Accel_y : " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Accel_z"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Accel_y"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Accel_z : " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Start Service " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Stop Service" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emoTracker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Accel_z"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:text="Enter your Emotion: " />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Stop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/positionTracker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/emoTracker"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emoTracker"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="Enter your postional state" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerEmotion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Accel_z"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/startService" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerPosition"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerEmotion"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/startService" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Accel_z"
        android:text="Neutral-Story" 
        android:textSize="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/stopService"
        android:text="Streesed-Story"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:text="Exciting Story"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Story.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rasam.androidacceleromter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service 
            android:name="AccelLoggerService"

           >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
            android:name = "com.rasam.androidacceleromter.AccelLoggerService">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name=".StoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.rasam.androidacceleromter.StoryActivity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have solved my problem ! The reason was I created the xml file manually form the XML tab, not from the android tab in the New File options !!! That solved the problem !